# How to indicate deleted text in manuscript when using highlighted text as opposed to tracked changes

Tags: publications, peer-review

I have the chance to submit a revised manuscript to a journal, and they have specifically asked to highlight the changes using highlighted text, as opposed to tracked changes. I am using Microsoft word.

I have always used tracked changes, so I am not sure of the normal procedure when using highlighted text to mark changes, specifically when deleting text. If there is a sentence to be deleted, how do you indicate this using highlighted text, as there is no text remaining. Should I just delete and then reference the line at which this happened in the response to editors and reviewers? Or should I highlight the 'space' where the line used to be?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <strike>strikethrough</strike> in [Word](https://www.howtogeek.com/361599/how-to-draw-a-line-through-words-in-microsoft-word/) (or [LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/strikethrough-text)).

Comment: Ah ok, so the text doesn't actually get removed from the manuscript, that's great thanks. Is it common practice to highlight the strikethrough text, or only highlight the new text?

Comment: @AP30 Strictly speaking, a strikethrough is a highlight. That said, it is unclear what the journal require, so highlighting [the backrgound], as per other changes, might be useful.